# Google apps scripts function to delete multiple gmail lables with one function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have many labels that I'm going to schedule them being deleted weekly.

I googled and found this function deletes one label:

```
function Delete_old_mail() {const threads = GmailApp.search("older_than:1w label:test-lable1");for (const thread of threads) {thread.moveToTrash();}};
```

But I'm going to delete multiple labels on a weekly basis:

```
test-label1
test-label2
test-label3
```

This is what I added in the project:

```
function Delete_old_mail() {const threads = GmailApp.search("older_than:1w label:test-lable1");for (const thread of threads) {thread.moveToTrash();}};
function Delete_old_mail() {const threads = GmailApp.search("older_than:1w label:test-lable2");for (const thread of threads) {thread.moveToTrash();}};
function Delete_old_mail() {const threads = GmailApp.search("older_than:1w label:test-lable3");for (const thread of threads) {thread.moveToTrash();}};
```

But I know it's not correct because when I'm going to add a new trigger, it detects `Delete_old_mail` function one time.

How can I have one function to delete multiple labels?

In real-world I have around 100 labels and defining 100 triggers is not easy, and I think managing them under one function will be easier, because for this 100 labels, I don't need emails older than a week.

**Edit1 for comments of the answers**

```
// Weekly Delete
function delete_older_than_7days_v1() {
  var labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4']
  labels.forEach(x => {
  const threads = GmailApp.search(`older_than:7d label: ${x}`);
  for (const thread of threads) {
    thread.moveToTrash();
    }
  })
}

function delete_older_than_7days_v2() {
  const labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4']; // Please set your expected label names.

  GmailApp.search(`older_than:7d {${labels.map(e => `label:${e}`).join(" ")}}`).forEach(t => t.moveToTrash());
}

// Monthly Delete
function delete_older_than_30days_v1() {
  var labels = ['label5', 'label6', 'label7']
  labels.forEach(x => {
  const threads = GmailApp.search(`older_than:7d label: ${x}`);
  for (const thread of threads) {
    thread.moveToTrash();
    }
  })
}

function delete_older_than_30days_v2() {
  const labels = ['label5', 'label6', 'label7']; // Please set your expected label names.

  GmailApp.search(`older_than:30d {${labels.map(e => `label:${e}`).join(" ")}}`).forEach(t => t.moveToTrash());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recommended:

The script below loops on the array of labels and searches for emails older than 7 days or 1 week under the specified labels.

```
function Delete_old_mail() {
  var labels = ["test-lable1", "test-lable2", "test-lable3"]
  labels.forEach(x => {
  const threads = GmailApp.search(`older_than:7d label: ${x}`);
  for (const thread of threads) {
    thread.moveToTrash();
  
    }
    
  })
}
```

**References:**

- [Gmail search operator](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)
- [forEach](https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script)

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- About `older_than`, the official document says `Search for messages older or newer than a time period using d (day), m (month), and y (year)`. In the current stage, in order to use 1 week, you can use `7d` instead of `1w`. This has already been mentioned in another answer.
- From your showing script, I thought that multiple labels could be searched by one search query like `{label:test-lable1 label:test-lable2 label:test-lable3}` as `OR`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const labels = ["test-lable1", "test-lable2", "test-lable3"]; // Please set your expected label names.

  GmailApp.search(`older_than:7d {${labels.map(e => `label:${e}`).join(" ")}}`).forEach(t => t.moveToTrash());
}
```

- When this script is run, the threads older than 1 week with the labels "test-lable1" or "test-lable2" or "test-lable3" are moved to the trash.

#### References:

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)